# Google Closure Compiler Fuzzer Config

Tags: java, config, google-closure-compiler, fuzzer

I am trying to run the google closure compiler fuzzer, but it's asking for a config file.

In the /build/classes/ directory I run

```
java -cp ../compiler.jar com.google.javascript.jscomp.fuzzing.Driver --number_of_runs 5 --config
```

It returns

```
Option "--config" takes an operand
```

Can anyone tell me what the config is supposed to look like or where I can find it? Thanks.

Comment: please provide more information on how you try to run it and your environment.

Comment: Further discussion on the mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/closure-compiler-discuss/2Z7t6w4rJSc

Answer (score 0):

Solved. There is a missing json file that will be changed soon.